# Minor enhancement: Captcha after all post verification

Tags: bug, status-completed

Minor annoyance: I entered the captcha then it told me I could not post because I was trying to create a new tag. I removed the "new" tag and then had to enter the captcha again (Which is a pita).

Also: I would like to see a human verification "slider" instead of captcha. The human moves the slider to mate up with an tick, or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Good point -- I changed the logic so that once you pass a CAPTCHA (and have at least 200 reputation), your user is whitelisted for the next 5 minutes and won't get another one for at least that long.

Comment: Should a user with the minimum required reputation be trusted enough to ask questions without captcha at all?